# Titanium appcelerator Wordpress api - shows html

Tags: json, api, parsing, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm having problems with an app project I'm working on. 
I'm parsing text from a wordpress api but it is coming out in html form. Any one knows how to work around this and get it in clean text format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from wordpress side not #appcelerator side ! , you can using `wp_strip_all_tags($html)` function to strip all HTML tags including script and style .

But if you are not wordpress coder and you want solve this probelem you can use any `javascript` function to strip html tags like :

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Comment: Thx! That helped ;) side questions I'm having trouble with my image view not showing the image from the api. You have any idea why?

Comment: Yes sure , i make alot of apps depend wordpress and woocommerce for ex http://goo.gl/remjU3 . Can you write the image url ? to see what is the problem . don`t forgot please make my answer is the correct answer if it really helped you  :)

Comment: http://mikehemmingsen.dk/shop/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/intense-workout-plan.jpg

Comment: The is that im not sure that i am calling it the right way :/ i dont suppose that you have a simple example on how to call an image from a recent post? :/

Comment: i am using that ;) to call the image im using doing it like this:
 `var image = json.posts[i]...;` and then in the imageView: `image:image`
but i must be doing somthing wrong since i don't get it right :/

Comment: You should ask new question :)